# How long do pre-chopped portobello mushrooms last in the refrigerator?

Tags: food-safety, storage-method, food-science, mushrooms

I'm looking to clean, wash, and pre-chop about 10lbs of portobello mushrooms. Will they be the same quality in the refrigerator for about 24 hours?

This is in an effort to find more efficient preparation methods. Is there a most suitable way to store them for 24 hours?

Comment: You may be able to use a quicker method for chopping (like a mandolin), which would mean you don't need to chop the day before.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably way too late, but for the benefit of others with the same question...
I have been taught, and my experiences verify, that fresh mushrooms of any sort should only be washed if absolutely necessary and if do so, to do it at the last possible moment. I just brush off any noticeable growing media and continue on. For Portobello mushrooms, I do this while cleaning out the "Gills" so it takes no extra time whatsoever.
That said, Pre-chopping / slicing, will reduce the shelf life over the long term, but for an overnight stay in the fridge it will not be a problem.
I would love to hear how you made out. Did you end up washing them? Your experience will also help others with the same question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't usually wash mushrooms either. I included that in my question because I had never actually verified that washing wasn't something that was necessary for mushrooms. Figured that it would be easiest to get that verified here. I actually didn't end up pre-prepping mushrooms. Had to refocus my prep for the day but I was able to get the mix done the next day no problem. Still your reply is much appreciated! Thanks for sharing!